# how to create a testcase with the provided angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, automated-tests

I'm new with angular and have some questions with testing. Below is part of the code on the homecompoonent.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mapService.mapLoaded$.subscribe(
      state => {
        this.loadingState = state;
      }
    );
    if (!this.isMobile || this.selectedView === 'map') {
      this.mapService.canLoadMap$.next(true);
    } else { this.mapService.triggerMapLoadedTransition(); }
    this.filterService.canLoadFilter$.next(true);
  }

I am trying to test the map service and filter service but couldn't make it work. here's the code so far:
 it('should trigger canLoadFilter to equal to true', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
  let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  component.selectedView = 'test';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(partialFilterService.canLoadFilter$.next).toEqual(true);
  });
I'm not sure with mapservice yet but any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
```

Comment: you should subscribe to partialFilterService.canLoadFilter$ and compare the values in the subscribtion the `next` function return void something like  partialFilterService.canLoadFilter$.subscribe((res) => res.toEqual(true))

Comment: I'm not following...

Answer (score 0):

You can`t expect the next **function** to return true.
To check canLoadFilter$ is pushing a true in the observable. You should subscribe to canLoadFilter$ to check if it is returning the true value

```
  describe('on init', () => {
    fit(`should push a true value in the observable`, async(() => { // use waitForAsync in lastest angular versions
      const filterService = TestBed.inject(FilterService); // use TestBed.get in previous angular versions 
      filterService.canLoadFilter$.subscribe((val) => {
        expect(val).toEqual('true');
      })
      fixture.detectChanges();
    }));
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run it: ERROR in src/app/views/home/home.component.spec.ts:126:27 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"true"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<boolean>'.

126       expect(val).toEqual('true');
                              ~~~~~~

Comment: I removed the '' on the parameter toEqual(true); and it worked. Thank you for your help. is there any other test cases you can think of other than testing the function to return the way it's supposed to be? I guess this applies to mapservice as well.